# Add cross browser for multiple packages using TestNG and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, testng, browserstack

I am using xml file to run all my packages of a project parallel, how to add cross browser to this xml file:

```xml
<suite name="Web Smoke Tests" verbose="1" preserve-order="true"
parallel="tests" thread-count="4">
<test name="Test2">
    <classes>
        <class name="package.class2"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="package.class1"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="package.class"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following sample for achieving this:
Modify your xml file based on the below sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel" thread-count="4" parallel="tests">
    <test name="SingleTestChrome">
        <parameter name="config" value="parallel.conf.json"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.browserstack.SingleTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SingleTestFirefox">
        <parameter name="config" value="parallel.conf.json"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.browserstack.SingleTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SingleTestSafari">
        <parameter name="config" value="parallel.conf.json"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="safari"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.browserstack.SingleTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SingleTestIE">
        <parameter name="config" value="parallel.conf.json"/>
        <parameter name="environment" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.browserstack.SingleTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Sample Configuration file:

```
{
    "server": "hub-cloud.browserstack.com",
    "user": "BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME",
    "key": "BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY",
    "capabilities": {
        "build": "testng-browserstack",
        "name": "parallel_test",
        "browserstack.debug": true
    },
    "environments": {
        "chrome": {
            "browser": "chrome"
        },
        "firefox": {
            "browser": "firefox"
        },
        "safari": {
            "browser": "safari"
        },
        "ie": {
            "browser": "internet explorer"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/browserstack/testng-browserstack

Comment: so if i have singletest, singletest1 and singletest2, i need to repeat the steps and it would be 3 times of the example you showed is it ?

Comment: You only need to ensure that your xml file is inline with the example I shared. I used 4 tests in the sample, you will only have 3